# svg animation - laggy on chrome, not in firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, d3.js, css-animations

I have an issue with Chrome, all the animations are laggy. (see project below)
I use CSS animation and WAAPI.

I am only using d3 and scrollama.

Here is my project: https://github.com/loicfontaine/visualdon-projet

deployed: https://sleep.lfontaine.ch/

I read some blog that were saying animated stroke-dasharray animation that I used to animate the graphs when you scroll could be laggy on chrome.  But I am still experiencing the same issue when I only have the clouds animated which aren't using that.

Do you have any idea how I can resolve this ?

Many thanks,
Loïc